# how to display coreData on a collection view cell (swift4)

Tags: ios, core-data, uicollectionview, swift4

My code below would work if it was displayed on a label. But in this function I am getting the error message Missing return in a function expected to return 'UICollectionViewCell'. Putting the return cell in the for loop does not work.

```
       import UIKit

class collectionVIEW: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

        var users = [User]()
    @IBOutlet var theIssues: UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//        users = cdHandler.fetchObject()!

    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return users.count

    }

    func getDefaultCell() -> UICollectionViewCell{
                    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! whyCollectionViewCell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        if cdHandler.fetchObject() != nil {
            users = cdHandler.fetchObject()!

            for c in users {

                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! whyCollectionViewCell
                cell.general.text = "\((cell.general.text)!)+\((c.userName)!)"

                return cell
            }

        } else {
            return getDefaultCell()
        }



    }




}
```

[image]

Comment: Regarding the screenshot: Please read the error message and compare both `dequeue...` lines. Hint: case sensitivity matters. The repeat loop in `cellForItem` is still pointless.

Comment: @vadian I tried changing dequeue and that had no effect I updated the question with all of my code.

Comment: Please learn to understand how a table view works. `cellForItemAt` is called  **multiple times separately for each row** . The `users` array must be populated outside of `cellForItemAt`. The fetch as well as the repeat loop is nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

`cellForItemAt` method expects to return UICollectionViewCell in all cases.  In the `else` condition, return a default cell as below:-

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if cdHandler.fetchObject() != nil {
        users = cdHandler.fetchObject()!

        for c in users {

       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! whyCollectionViewCell
            cell.general.text = "\((cell.general.text)!)+\((c.userName)!)"

        return cell
                }

        }else{
           return getDefaultCell()
}
```

Note:-Register collection view with identifier `defaultCcell`

```
func getDefaultCell() -> UICollectionViewCell{
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "defaultCcell", for: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
return cell 
}
```

Comment: The getDefualtcell func is not working I added a photo above for you to see the error. Thanks.

Comment: Replace collectionVIEW with name of your collection view.

Comment: Did that still getting a error message. Updated a photo above. Thanks.

Comment: Pass the index path as parameter to that function and use it.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I updated my question with all of my code if that helps.